# I put in 21 and it prints out the answer is wrong even though it is right I dont know why

Tags: python

```
question = input("what is 8 + 13? ")
math = 8 + 13
if question == 21:
  print("that is correct")
if question != 21:
  print("That is wrong")
```

#when i put in 21 it prints that is wrong instead of correct, why.
#I thought it was becuase it was comparing a int and a str but I dont know how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

make sure you type cast. inputs are strings by default

```py
question = int(input("what is 8 + 13? "))
math = 8 + 13
if question == 21:
  print("that is correct")
if question != 21:
  print("That is wrong")
```